# c# error returning value from function

Tags: c#, .net, function, ref

I am tring to use a method or function to create the directory tree that I need, and return the new path to the calling procedure.

But I cannot get it to compile

I get an error `cannot convert method group 'localAttachmentsPath' to non delegate type string ..`

here is my code - what have I done wrong? And is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
        private string localAttachmentsPath(ref string emailAttachmentsPath)
        {

            string sYear = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
            string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
            string sDirectoryDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

            if (!Directory.Exists(emailAttachmentsPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(emailAttachmentsPath);

            }

            emailAttachmentsPath = emailAttachmentsPath + "\\" + sYear;
            if (!Directory.Exists(emailAttachmentsPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(emailAttachmentsPath);
            }

            emailAttachmentsPath = emailAttachmentsPath + "\\" + sMonth;
            if (!Directory.Exists(emailAttachmentsPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(emailAttachmentsPath);
            }

            emailAttachmentsPath = emailAttachmentsPath + "\\" + sDirectoryDate;
            if (!Directory.Exists(emailAttachmentsPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(emailAttachmentsPath);
            }

            //localAttachmentsPath = emailAttachmentsPath;
            return localAttachmentsPath;

        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to return?  All you're doing at the minute is returning a reference to your own function, not a value.  If you want to return emailAttachementsPath just put "return emailAttachmentsPath", you don't need to set the name of the function to the return value (is that VB syntax?)

Comment: And just so you know, `CreateDirectory` already creates the whole tree if you pass a full path, you dont need to create it subfolder by subfolder...

Comment: @Bartdude: thanks, now I don't need a function :)

Comment: I almost wrote an answer out of this actually. Indeed, you can replace the whole function by a single line of code for the same effect. Here's another piece of advice : when you're not sure, read the doc and/or try it... it would have saved you some time I guess ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your return type as `void` and remove `return` statement as you are passing variable `emailAttachmentsPath` as reference variable so it wouldbe updated from the caller without return statement.

Your Method should look like:

```
private void localAttachmentsPath(ref string emailAttachmentsPath)
{

//your code

//no return statement

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply specify the value you want to return, like this:

```
return emailAttachmentsPath;
```

I would also recommend you drop the `ref` keywordfrom the parameter.

**Further Reading**

- [`ref` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)
- [`return` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is this:

```
return localAttachmentsPath;
```

That is a function, I think you want to declare a local variable with some other name than the function name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ref string emailAttachmentsPath` than you do not need to return any string